# Format output to lowercase

Tags: php, format

I need to change the output of `<?php echo $EM_Category->name; ?>` to lowercase only.

Output now is `Entertainment`. How would I get it to `entertainment`

Full section of code is:

```
<?php foreach(EM_Categories::get(array('orderby'=>'category_name')) as $EM_Category): ?>
<a href="<?php echo THEME_URL; ?>/events/category/<?php echo $EM_Category->name; ?>" class="browse-cat">
   <span><?php echo $EM_Category->name; ?></span><img src="<?php echo THEME_URL; ?>/images/box_arrow.png" alt="arrow" height="15" width="15">
</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the `EM_Categories` class?

Comment: Dang downvotes all around for that one.  Sorry for using stack! jeesh...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?php echo strtolower($EM_Category->name); ?>`

http://us.php.net/strtolower

Answer (score 3):

That would be the [strtolower](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) function.

```
<?php echo strtolower($EM_Category->name); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php echo strtolower($EM_Category->name); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you use:

```
echo strtolower($EM_Category->name);
```